# How can I use heat.exe (or similar) to harvest COM registration from a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows, service, wix, cruisecontrol.net

How can I use heat.exe (or similar) to harvest COM registration from a Windows Service?

I have used heat.exe (or really using DllHarvester class through Wix) to harvest COM and .Net registrations for a installation package on a Windows 2003 server for years. Due to IT-deparment demands I am now forced to upgrade the server and switch to a more "modern" OS (i.e. 2012R2). But after migrating everything to the new OS I have started loosing about 1/3 of all registration information. Tracking it down shows it being related to some older 3rd party COM files.

Further tracking seems to indicate that harvesting works just fine when run from an Interactive user account (logged in to desktop) using an elevated process. However running it from a service does not (I am using a CruiseControl.Net build server running as service using a user account in the administrator group).

Experimenting further using Task Scheduler I find that "Running when the user is logged on" works but "Running whether or not user is logged on" does not work.

I have tried to get a LogonUser/CreateProcessAsUser re-launcher but it is very complicated and I have failed to get it working.

I guess that running as a logged on user creates a different registry view but I do not really know why this would impact on a COM-registration?

Is there any way to get harvesting working from a service on a modern OS (preferably on W2k12R2)?

Comment: Is this a programming problem, or an issue with a tool?

Comment: Good comment. As a programmer (forced to do packaging work) I do search for a programmatic solution. I.e. Can I change my code somehow to get this working. If someone can confirm it is a tools issue I will remove the question. But as I said: My harvester does not work from TaskScheduler either so it is not really related to the tool (Cruise Control.Net). Rather it is programming a harvester from a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the harvester using psexec from sysinternals

> psexec -h ...

on your own machine.